# Error in excel import :Finding error while importing excel to SQL in SSIS with large text column

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, msbi

I am trying to import the excel to SQL server table using SSIS package . In that excel one column has data more than 300 characters. While importing I am getting an error in excel source:

> [Excel Source [12]] Error: There was an error with Excel
>   Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output].Columns [ higher] on Excel
>   Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output]. The column status returned was: 
>   "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the
>   target code page.".

Action taken:Tried by changing the data type as "Unicode text stream" by property Show advanced editor->input & output properties->external output columns.

Comment: Why not define your SQL destination field as varchar(max)  or Nvarchar(max) just to see if this is the field causing the problem?

Comment: We tried that also.  When we execute the package. At the excel source it self the issue is coming

Comment: Try to create a new excel source using this file and you will get the right metatdata of columns

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your mapping in ssis is smaller than the real value in Excel, or your excel text have some character that your code page can't read.

You can unmap and map again your columns in the excel source or go to:

> [Excel Source [12]] right click >> "Show Advanced Editor..." >> "Input and Output properties" >> "OLE DB Source Output" >> " + Output Columns"

and edit the commom Propertie "CodePage" and "Length" of your column.

If it doesn't work, try to ignore truncation errors on "Error Output" page.

Comment: When I am trying to import that particular column alone, I can able to do. But when I am importing the whole sheet I am facing the issue. when trying with single Column the datatype is unicode text stream . But when importing with all the sheet the datatype is taking as unicode string.

Comment: you can change the data type of the column to whatever you want in the advanced editor ...

Comment: Yes,  at beginning itself I have checked it.